# Python / Pandas: Eliminate for Loop using 2 DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

First time asking a question here so hopefully I will make my issue clear. I am trying to understand how to better apply a list of scenarios (via for loop) to the same dataset and summarize results. *Note that once a scenario is applied, and I pull the relevant statistical data from dataframe and put into the summary table, I do not need to retain the information. Iterrows is painfully slow as I have tens of thousands of scenarios I want to run. Thank you for taking the time to review.

I have two Pandas dataframes: df_analysts and df_results:

1)  df_analysts contains a specific list of factors (e.g. TB,JK,SF,PWR) scenarios of weights (e.g. 50,50,50,50)

```
      TB   JK   SF  PWR
0     50   50   50   50
1     50   50   50  100
2     50   50   50  150
3     50   50   50  200
4     50   50   50  250
```

2) df_results holds results by date and group and entrant an then ranking by each factor, finally it has the final finish result.

```
      Date       GR  Ent TB-R  JK-R  SF-R  PWR-R Fin   W1  W2  W2  W4  SUM(W)
0     11182017   1   1   2     1     2     1     2
1     11182017   1   2   3     2     3     2     1
2     11182017   1   3   1     3     1     3     3
3     11182017   2   1   1     2     2     1     1
4     11182017   2   2   2     1     1     2     1
```

3) I am using iterrows to

1. loop through each scenario in the df_analysts dataframe
2. apply weight scenario to each factor rank  (if rank = 1, then 1.0*weight, rank = 2, then 0.68*weight, rank = 3, then 0.32*weight). Those results go into the W1-W4 columns.
3. Sum the W1-W4 columns.
4. Rank the SUM(W) column.

Result sample below for a single scenario (e.g. 50,50,50,50)

```
      Date       GR  Ent TB-R  JK-R  SF-R  PWR-R Fin   W1  W2  W2  W4  SUM(W) Rank
0     11182017   1   1   2     1     2     1     1     34  50  34  50  168    1
1     11182017   1   2   3     2     3     2     3     16  34  16  34  100    3
2     11182017   1   3   1     3     1     3     2     50  16  50  16  132    2
3     11182017   2   1   2     2     2     1     1     34  34  34  50  152    2  
4     11182017   2   2   1     1     1     2     1     50  50  50  34  184    1
```

4) Finally, for each scenario, I am creating a new dataframe for the summary results (df_summary) which logs the factor / weight scenario used (from df_analysts)  and compares the RANK result to the Finish by date and group and keeps a tally where they land. Sample below (only the 50,50,50,50 scenario is shown above which results in a 1,1).

```
      Factors          Weights         Top  Top2
0     (TB,JK,SF,PWR)   (50,50,50,50)   1    1
1     (TB,JK,SF,PWR)   (50,50,50,100)  1    0
2     (TB,JK,SF,PWR)   (50,50,50,150)  1    1
3     (TB,JK,SF,PWR)   (50,50,50,200)  1    0
4     (TB,JK,SF,PWR)   (50,50,50,250)  1    1
```

Comment: I don't like the way step 3 has other numbered steps in it.

Comment: I think in this case it would be better to drop (4) and just focus on (3) as that's a target for removing a `for` loop. There's quite a lot going on in this question

Comment: @ChrisM I did that. Check my edit, beforehand it was just a single block of text. How else do you think it should be broken down? I could change to bullet points if that's better? But certainly I couldn't follow it with it all packed into a single paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge your analyst and results dataframe and then perform the calculations.

```
def factor_rank(x,y):
    if (x==1): return y
    elif (x==2): return y*0.68
    elif (x==3): return y*0.32


df_analysts.index.name='SCENARIO'
df_analysts.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_analysts['key'] = 1
df_results['key'] = 1

df = pd.merge(df_analysts, df_results, on='key')
df.drop(['key'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df['W1'] = df.apply(lambda r: factor_rank(r['TB-R'], r['TB']), axis=1)
df['W2'] = df.apply(lambda r: factor_rank(r['JK-R'], r['JK']), axis=1)
df['W3'] = df.apply(lambda r: factor_rank(r['SF-R'], r['SF']), axis=1)
df['W4'] = df.apply(lambda r: factor_rank(r['PWR-R'], r['PWR']), axis=1)
df['SUM(W)'] = df.W1 + df.W1 + df.W3 + df.W4

df["rank"] = df.groupby(['GR','SCENARIO'])['SUM(W)'].rank(ascending=False)
```

You may also want to check out this question which deals with improving processing times on row based calculations:

[How to apply a function to mulitple columns of a pandas DataFrame in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718865/how-to-apply-a-function-to-mulitple-columns-of-a-pandas-dataframe-in-parallel)

Comment: Thanks Alex, this does work, however my original code applies the scenario to the results data frame, I then evaluate the results and store in the summary dataframe, then the next scenario is applied to the results data frame again (overiding the previous results. So if my results dataframe is 464 rows, it is always 464 rows. A 4 factor / 5 weight scenarios is (625*464 = 290000 rows).  A 7 factor / 5 weight is 16k scenerios (16k * 464 = 7 million+. Is that really efficient? I dont need to retain all the results. I can just summarize and move on. Thoughts?